# Can MySQL properly sort DATETIME columns when the values have been formatted with DATE_FORMAT?

Tags: mysql, datetime, date

Pretty much self-explanatory. Can MySQL sort dates (i.e. not alphabetically but like a date) when the dates have been formatted with `DATE_FORMAT`?

Specifically, in my case, only the DATE part has been extracted from the DATETIME values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

```
ORDER BY DATE(`date_time`) DESC
```

If you have already calculated this when selecting columns, just use its alias.

```
SELECT DATE(`date_time`) AS `date`
    FROM `table`
ORDER BY `date` DESC
```

Comment: Excellent; thank you. I'll accept this answer once SO lets me.